# How to run .NET CORE MVC in debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am tackling my first .net core mvc project. I've worked with .net framework 4.5 mvc in the past and was able to put breakpoints while executing the application.

When trying to execute the application, it tries to load http://localhost:62114/ and then after maybe ~10 seconds the application shut down.

The only way I've successfully been able to execute my program is by going to project root directly and executing `dotnet run` in the CMD prompt

```
Hosting environment: Development
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

May I ask is there a way to execute my application without going through CMD and having a debugger present.

Project Debug Settings

[image]

Comment: Try changing the port number, editing IIS Express config by hand, break on every CLR exception, ....

Comment: @Master Is there anything extraordinary on the Output window before it shuts down?